# Unable to uninstall a package (gns3-gui)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, uninstall

I have installed the GNS3 server and client separately on Ubuntu 20.0.4. when I check the packages list, GNS3 (GUI) is available:

```
test@gns3vm:/$ dpkg -l gns3*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version       Architecture Description
+++-==============-=============-============-=================================
un  gns3           <none>        <none>       (no description available)
ii  gns3-iou       0.0.3~focal1  amd64        GNS3 support for IOU
hi  gns3-server    2.2.29~focal1 amd64        GNS3 server
```

The first line is the GNS3 GUI. But, when I want to uninstall it there is no GNS3 (GUI).

```
dpkg -r gns3-
gns3-iou     gns3-server
```

Do you have any idea about this problem? Is it possible to be the dpkg problem? How can I uninstall gns3 (GUI) only?

Comment: Your listing shows `gns3` as "not installed". So what is your problem? Specifically, what do you mean by "is available"?

Comment: Imean there is "gns3" command in Linux terminal and I open the gns3-gui by this command, @Tilman

Comment: If it is uninstalled, why the dpkg lists it? @Tilman

Comment: Because that's how `dpkg` works. For details see `man dpkg-query`.

Comment: If your problem is that the `gns3` command still works in spite of package `gns3` being uninstalled, please edit your question to say so. Include the output of the commands `which gns3` and `dpkg -S gns3`. I'll gladly expand my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you did not include any information on the steps you took to install this app.

This on-line guide explains [how to install GNS3-GUI](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-gns3-on-ubuntu/)

The basic 5 steps are:

- Run the following commands step-wise:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gns3/ppa`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install gns3-server gns3-gui`

- Allow non-root users to use wire-shark and capture packets as well.
- Install IOU Support (Optional)
- Docker Support (Optional)
- Launch GNS3 on Ubuntu 20.04

Complete GNS3 setup on Ubuntu 20.04 Linux.

You can find the same instructions for all the steps within the link provided.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem. The `dpkg` output you quote shows shows packagage `gns3` with status `n`, ie. "not installed". You cannot uninstall it because it is not installed in the first place.

Note that according to `man dpkg-query`, `dpkg -l <pattern>` lists not just installed packages, but *packages listed in the dpkg database*, which may include uninstalled and half-installed packages. You need to consult the `Status` column to know its actual status.